# ¿Cómo generar una tabla con distintas columnas cuyos registros se obtienen desde una misma función?

Tags: sql-server, join

Tengo una función que rompe una cadena `ntext` en varias partes según se halle el marcador `|` y genera una tabla `splitdata` con una única columna con el mismo nombre que contiene todas las partes de la cadena que se separaron. Utilizo algunos `where` ... `like` para obtener ciertos resultados de esa tabla y uso `Union` para que cada resultado que busque se agregue en `splitdata`, pero lo que quiero hacer es que cada `where` ... `like`  se agregue en una columna propia para que al final se pueda llamar desde un RecordSet en vb y rellenar algunos objetos en un formulario.

El procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[respuestaSPLIT] (@cuenta NVARCHAR(max)) as DECLARE @ans NVARCHAR(max);                                                                      
    SELECT @ans = [respuesta] FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] WHERE [id_cuenta]= @cuenta;                                                                         

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbnacionalidad.%'       
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbocupacion.%' 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbprofesion.%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbgiro.%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbentidad.%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'txtfirma.%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'txtcalleResidencia.%'
```

Y me genera esto (hay algunos espacios en blanco despues del '.' porque así está en la cadena que se rompe):

> splitdata
>
> ---
>
> cmbentidad.1
>
> cmbgiro.
>
> cmbnacionalidad.México
>
> cmbocupacion.
>
> cmbprofesion.
>
> txtcalleResidencia.Sierra Vertientes
>
> txtfirma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que tu consulta de unions se puede escribir en una sola en la cual adicionas en el where los filtros de cada union con OR asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[respuestaSPLIT] (@cuenta NVARCHAR(max)) as DECLARE @ans NVARCHAR(max);                                                                      
SELECT @ans = [respuesta] FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] WHERE [id_cuenta]= @cuenta;                                                                         

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbnacionalidad.%' 
OR [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbocupacion.%' 
OR [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbprofesion.%'
OR [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbgiro.%'
OR [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbentidad.%'
OR [splitdata] LIKE 'txtfirma.%'
OR [splitdata] LIKE 'txtcalleResidencia.%'
```

Si entiendo bien tu requerimiento, quieres que cada union vaya en una columna nueva, esto lo haces con subconsultas, así:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[respuestaSPLIT] (@cuenta NVARCHAR(max)) as DECLARE @ans NVARCHAR(max);                                                                      
        SELECT @ans = [respuesta] FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] WHERE [id_cuenta]= @cuenta;                                                                         

SELECT     
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbnacionalidad.%') as cmbnacionalidad,
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbocupacion.%') as cmbocupacion, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbprofesion.%') as cmbprofesion,
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbgiro.%') as cmbgiro,
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'cmbentidad.%') as cmbentidad,
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'txtfirma.%') as txtfirma,
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|') where [splitdata] LIKE 'txtcalleResidencia.%') as txtcalleResidencia;
```

El TOP 1 es necesario por que las subconsultas en este sql, deben devolver un solo dato. Si tu función fnSplitString devuelve más de un dato para cada consulta esta solución no te sirve y el tema es más complejo.

Saludos,

Comment: GRACIAS por tu ayuda! La parte del `OR` es correcta. En la segunda parte tienes razón, lo que quiero es que me genera una columna por cada registro encontrado, no como en la primera parte; el código que propones me pone este error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.` para todas las lineas que crean las columnas.

Comment: Ya probé individualmente estas lineas:
`SELECT top 1 * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] ('algo|algo2|algo3|algo4|algo33','|')` y genera `algo`. Luego 

`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] ('algo|algo2|algo3|algo4|algo33','|') WHERE [splitdata] LIKE 'algo3%' ` y genera `algo3,algo33`,

Comment: `SELECT top 1  * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] ('algo|algo2|algo3|algo4|algo33','|') WHERE [splitdata] LIKE 'algo3%'` me genera `algo3`. Pero cuando agrego `as` me bota el mismo error @Jorge Londoño

Comment: ok  ya lo reviso y te lo envio

Comment: amigo, faltaba el select .., estoy instalando sql server en mi maquina y valido, saludos

Comment: Eres un genio!. Quedó tal como quería. Agradezco tu ayuda inmensamente. Saludos

Comment: :) me alegra, saludos!